# CPU on IIS server pegged at 100% in BufferAllocator.GetBuffer()

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, cpu-usage

I have an IIS7 application pool that handles a large number of RESTful requests. When things get heated, the CPU usage hits 100% and the requests take many seconds to be processed.

When profiling with ANTS, we found that very often most of the CPU time goes here:

```
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
 System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
  (Unmanaged code)
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification
    System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper
     System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate
      System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification
       System.Web.HttpApplication+PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps
        System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep
         System.Web.HttpApplication+CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
          System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput
           System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated
            System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetBufferedResponseChunks
             System.Web.Hosting.RecyclableArrayHelper.GetIntegerArray
              >> System.Web.BufferAllocator.GetBuffer
               (Thread blocked)
              >> System.Web.BufferAllocator.ReuseBuffer
               (Thread blocked)
```

There are actually several different stack traces, but they all invariably end in `GetBuffer()` or `ReuseBuffer()`.

Both `GetBuffer()` and `ReuseBuffer()` begin with a `lock()`, so I figure the CPU spends a lot of time in a spinlock (my understanding is that `lock` spins for a bit before putting the thread to sleep).

My question - is this a common place for the CPU to be spending its time on? This is all entirely in IIS code, so what can I do to reduce the CPU load? Is that a configuration issue, or is this the result of actions that our application did earlier?

The machines are pretty beefy, they have 4 quadcores. I don't have the number of threads running currently available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty much what we suspected - the threads were all spending a stupid amount of time in the spinlock, since they all compete for the same lock. We had hundreds of threads.

The fix was to have more processes with fewer threads - now the CPU usage is reasonable.